# Modify column value based on the first occurance for every nth rows, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame like this

```
ID,A,B
1,Fruit,Orange
1,Fruit,Apple
3,Fruit,Mango
4,Fruit,Banana
5,Fruit,PineApple
5,Fruit,Grapes
```

I want to modify every 3 rows in a such way that they will have a common ID. The Id I want to apply is the first ID occurrence for that every 3 rows.

Output would be

```
ID,A,B
1,Fruit,Orange
1,Fruit,Apple
1,Fruit,Mango
4,Fruit,Banana
4,Fruit,PineApple
4,Fruit,Grapes
```

Can you suggest, how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with groups created by integer division:

```
#if default RangeIndex
#df['ID'] = df.groupby(df.index // 3)['ID'].transform('first')
#general solution
df['ID'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3)['ID'].transform('first')
print (df)
   ID      A          B
0   1  Fruit     Orange
1   1  Fruit      Apple
2   1  Fruit      Mango
3   4  Fruit     Banana
4   4  Fruit  PineApple
5   4  Fruit     Grapes
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
```